# How to COMPLETELY remove a background in MatLab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, background

I am trying to remove a background using MatLab.

I have achieved what looks like very good results using the traditional

```
imsubtracted = im - background;
```

However, the blackness that has replaced the background is not pure black. Further image processing reveals that there is a significant amount of noise left over. Is it possible to either completely remove the background or make it uniformly the same color?

Please note, I am dealing with very small objects in a rather large black space.

Comment: can you post your current results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you subtract the background, you should threshold the resulting image to create a binary foreground mask. Set all the differences less than a threshold to 0 (background), and set the ones greater than or equal to a threshold to 1 (foreground).  You can then use morphology such as `imopen` to get rid of small noisy specks in the background and `imclose` to get rid of small gaps or holes in the foreground.

Once you are happy with your foreground mask, you can use it as a logical index to set the background pixels to whatever color you choose.